# Tikz: flow diagram with graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am experimenting with fully automatic placement of flowcharts.
Without any coordinates and block names.

The problem with blocks that have multiple outputs.

I used the following trick:

```
a -!- { [nodes={xshift=-10mm}]
  (a.west) -> /,
  (a.east) -> /
}
```

The question is:

1. Is this a good solution or is there a more standard solution?
2. If not, how do I get rid of the name of the decision block?
   Is there a command with the name of the parent block?

Full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard, arrows, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikz [
>=stealth'
, ortho/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}}
, back/.style = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}}
, connection/.style={draw, circle, radius=5pt}
, operation/.style={draw, rectangle}
, decision/.style={draw, diamond}
]
\graph [
grow down sep
, branch right=20mm,
simple
] {
  start [draw, rectangle, rounded corners]
  -> /test [operation]
  -> a[decision]
  -!- { [nodes={xshift=-10mm}]
    (a.west) ->[ortho] /test [operation] -> /test [operation],
    (a.east) ->[ortho] d/test [decision]
    -!- { [nodes={xshift=-10mm}]
      (d.west) ->[ortho]  /test [operation],
      (d.east) ->[ortho] f/test [decision]
      -!- { [nodes={xshift=-10mm}]
        (f.west) ->[ortho] /test [operation],
        (f.east) ->[ortho] /test [operation] -> /test [operation]
      }
    }
  }
  -- [back] /[coordinate]
  -> /test [operation]
  -> end [draw, rectangle, rounded corners]
};
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! I think the approach is great. Of course, you could also use `forest` here.